# fullcalendar - Strange behavior after multiple click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, fullcalendar

I using Fullcalendar for a personal project (for family member) and i'd detect a strange behavior after many click on events, i explain

My eventClick open modal for edit them

```
eventClick: function(event, resourceObj) {
        //alert(resourceObj.title);
        let evt = {};
        let end = '';
        if(event.end) {
            evt['end'] = event.end.format();
        } else {
            evt['end'] = event.start.format();
        };
        evt['title'] = event.title;
        evt['resourceId'] = event.resourceId;
        evt['description'] = event.description;
        evt['color'] = event.color;
        evt['id'] = event.id;
        evt['start'] = event.start.format();
        openModal(evt);
        // mise a jour d'un event
        $('#formModal #newEventSubmit').on('click', function() {
            updateDate();
            if ($('#newEventTitle').val()) {
                var eventData = {
                    start: $('#newEventStart').val(),
                    end: $('#newEventEnd').val(),
                    resourceId: $('#newEventResource').val(),
                    description: $('#newEventDescription').val(),
                    title: $('#newEventTitle').val(),
                    color: $('#newEventColor').val(),
                    id: $('#newEventId').val(),
                    allDay: false
                };
                console.log(eventData);
                if($('#newEventStartH').val() == '' && $('#newEventEndH').val() == ''){
                    eventData['allDay'] = true;
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                putEvent(eventData, event);
            }
            $('#formModal').find('input').val('');
            $('#formModal').modal('hide');
        });
        // action pour delete un event
        $('#formModal #newEventDelete').on('click', function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
            deleteEvent(evt);
            $('#formModal').modal('hide');
            //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

        });

    },
```

OpenModal => create a modal with 2 button (update & delete)

When i click on event, close de modal, open another one and delete this => the deletion is for all event clicked

when i inspect the network, i watch all the id delete with my api rest

U understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because every time you click on an event, you execute

```
$('#formModal #newEventSubmit').on('click', function() {
```

and

```
$('#formModal #newEventDelete').on('click', function() {
```

Each of these adds a new event handling function to the modal's Submit and Delete buttons, to fire when the button is clicked. However, it doesn't remove all the previous event handlers. Therefore, if you click on several events, it will add more and more event handlers to the buttons. And then, when you click one of these buttons, it fires *all* of the attached event handlers at once - this is why you see lots of requests for the delete function, for example.

The simple solution to this is to remove previous event handlers before adding a new one. You can do this with jQuery's [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method:

```
$('#formModal #newEventSubmit').off('click').on('click', function() {
```

and

```
$('#formModal #newEventDelete').off('click').on('click', function() {
```